# DAX: Determinar llegadas retrasadas por responsable

Tags: powerbi, dax

Tengo la siguiente tabla de hechos, `facIncidencias`, con incidencias que pueden provocar o no retraso en la llegada de trenes:

```
co_inc;co_tipo_inc;fe_inc;co_tren;bo_retraso;ca_retraso;ca_clientes
1;3;02/01/2024;3;1;40;30
1;3;03/01/2024;1;1;25;90
1;3;04/01/2024;2;0;5;35
1;3;04/01/2024;5;0;10;15
2;5;03/01/2024;1;0;10;35
3;2;04/01/2024;4;0;15;25
3;2;05/01/2024;4;1;35;60
4;4;02/01/2024;3;1;65;30
5;1;07/01/2024;1;0;10;15
5;1;07/01/2024;3;0;0;45
5;1;08/01/2024;5;1;15;40
5;1;08/01/2024;3;1;0;45
5;1;11/01/2024;4;1;5;45
5;1;12/01/2024;2;1;10;80
6;3;15/01/2024;1;1;25;55
6;3;16/01/2024;2;0;5;90
7;5;15/01/2024;1;1;25;35
7;5;15/01/2024;2;1;65;45
7;5;16/01/2024;3;0;0;35
8;2;16/01/2024;5;0;5;30
8;2;17/01/2024;1;0;10;90
9;1;23/01/2024;5;1;35;65
10;4;23/01/2024;5;1;35;80
10;4;24/01/2024;4;1;10;75
10;4;25/01/2024;4;0;0;70
10;4;25/01/2024;3;1;5;50
10;4;25/01/2024;1;1;70;15
10;4;26/01/2024;4;0;0;25
10;4;27/01/2024;5;0;5;65
```

Leyenda:

- `co_inc`: Código de incidencia
- `co_tipo_inc`: Código de tipo de incidencia
- `fe_inc`: Fecha de incidencia
- `co_tren`: Código de tren
- `bo_retraso`: Valor lógico que indica si hubo (1) o no (0) llegada con
  retraso
- `ca_retraso`: Minutos de retraso que supuso la incidencia
- `ca_clientes`: Clientes afectados por la incidencia

También tengo la siguiente tabla de dimensiones, `dimIncidencias`, que indica qué operador es responsable de cada tipo de incidencia:

```
co_tipo_inc;en_operador
1;A
2;B
3;B
4;C
5;C
```

Necesitaría determinar el número de llegadas con retraso por operador sabiendo que, en caso de duplicidad (es decir, si para un mismo `co_tren` y una misma `fe_inc` hubo dos -o más- `co_inc` diferentes responsabilidad de dos -o más- `en_operador` diferentes con `co_retraso = 1`), se achaca el retraso a aquella incidencia con mayor `ca_retraso` y, en caso de empate, a aquella con mayor `ca_clientes`.

Por ejemplo:

```
co_inc;co_tipo_inc;fe_inc;co_tren;bo_retraso;ca_retraso;ca_clientes
9;1;23/01/2024;5;1;35;65
10;4;23/01/2024;5;1;35;80
```

Para este supuesto de `co_tren = 5` y `fe_inc = 23/01/2024`, `co_inc = 10` sería la relevante, puesto que a igualdad de `ca_retraso` tiene mayor `ca_clientes`; como `co_tipo_inc = 4`, la responsabilidad se le achacaría al operador `C`.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0):

He llegado a la siguiente solución:

```
llegadas_retrasadas =
VAR retrasos_minutos =
FILTER(
    facIncidencias,
    facIncidencias[bo_retraso] = 1
    && facIncidencias[ca_retraso] =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(facIncidencias[ca_retraso]),
        ALLEXCEPT(
            facIncidencias,
            facIncidencias[co_tren],
            facIncidencias[fe_inc]
        )
    )
)
VAR retrasos_clientes =
FILTER(
    retrasos_minutos,
    retrasos_minutos[ca_clientes] =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(retrasos_minutos[ca_clientes]),
        ALLEXCEPT(
            retrasos_minutos,
            retrasos_minutos[co_tren],
            retrasos_minutos[fe_inc]
        )
    )
)
VAR resultado = COUNTROWS(retrasos_clientes)
RETURN resultado
```

Desde un punto de vista lógico creo que tiene sentido, y debería devolverme el resultado que espero, el número total de llegadas con retraso achacables a cada operador en función de esos criterios de desempate, que luego se podrían segmentar en una visualización usando la columna `en_operador` de `dimIncidencias`.

Sin embargo, PBI tiene alguna restricción por la cual no me deja acceder desde la segunda variable a las columnas de la tabla virtual creada en la primera variable; por ejemplo, `retrasos_minutos[ca_clientes]` me lo subraya en rojo, dando a entender que no existe esa columna dentro de esa tabla (o variable).

El mensaje de error en concreto es:

> La variable de tabla 'retrasos_minutos' no se puede usar en el
> contexto actual porque se espera una tabla de base.

¿Alguna sugerencia?